# Adding to Github from Visual Studio 2013 not working as documented

Tags: github, visual-studio-2013

[This](http://michaelcrump.net/setting-up-github-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013-step-by-step/) is the online reference I am using. However when I enter the remote repository and hit publish I get an error

> You cannot publish local branch master to the remote repository origin
>   because a branch with the same name already exists there. You might
>   want to rename your local branch and try again.

I dont want to rename anything as yet. I want the first version of the code to go into the master branch and at the same time create an upstream tracking branch locally.

Then I tried using the command line only. After creating a fresh repository, I ran the following commands

```
$ cd (project-directory)
$ git init
$ (add some files)
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Initial commit'
$ git remote add origin <url>
$ git push --force
```

This worked but now I have all my obj,bin,packages directories along with it. I don't want all those directories to go. Editing the git ignore did not help either. What I am doing wrong? Its taken more twice the amount of time to get the code into the repository than it has taken to write the code!

I only want my sources in the repository and have a tracking local branch to begin with.

Comment: you add every thing by `$ git add .` , that's why it included binary files

Comment: how do I ignore  obj,bin,packages directories but add everything else?

Comment: You can do it by `.gitignore`, but seems you update it after you did the add and the commit, right?

Comment: I edited gitignore online and uncommented the packages line and then added and commited everything

Comment: show your `.gitignore` file

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3bB1Nzd8

Comment: You said you edited `gitignore` online, confirm you pulled it to your local repo. Commit any change you have then run `git rm -r --cached .` , then `git add .` and commit. worked?